# How to abstract constraints in function with Rank-2 type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, existential-type, constraint-kinds

The following snippet of code borrows from [the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Existential_types) to carry around a typeclass dictionary along with an existential type:

```
{-# language ExistentialQuantification #-}
module Experiment1 where

data Showable = forall x. Show x => Showable x
instance Show Showable where showsPrec p (Showable x) = showsPrec p x

resultStr :: String
resultStr = show (Showable ()) -- "()"
```

Is it possible to write a function `f :: (forall x. x -> result) -> result` that is able to take the `Showable` constructor (or any other data constructor to an existential type) as an argument?

One failed attempt at doing this looks like this:

```
{-# language ExistentialQuantification, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds #-}

module Experiment2 where

-- import Data.Constraint (Dict(..), withDict)

data Showable = forall x. Show x => Showable x
instance Show Showable where showsPrec p (Showable x) = showsPrec p x

f :: (cxt (), cxt result) => (forall x. cxt x => x -> result) -> result
f mkResult = mkResult ()

resultStr :: String
resultStr = show (f Showable)
```

As implied by my commented import above, I have the impression that the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package might allow me to pass around the necessary proofs, but I can't see how that would work?

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to determine what the constraint `cxt` is from the type `result`?

Comment: Good point, I was trying to infer the constraints from `mkResult` but of course there's no way of doing that. Looking at it now I suppose I was attempting to somehow define
`data Showable (cxt ~ Show) = forall x. cxt x => Showable x`
such that
`f :: (cxt (), cxt (result cxt)) => (forall x. cxt x => x -> result cxt) -> result cxt`
and infer `cxt` directly from `Showable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your failed attempt works if you provide a way to determine `cxt`

```
import Data.Proxy

f :: (cxt (), cxt result) => p cxt -> (forall x. cxt x => x -> result) -> result
f _ mkResult = mkResult ()

resultStr :: String
resultStr = show (f (Proxy :: Proxy Show) Showable)
```

Comment: Or `f :: forall cxt. (cxt (), cxt result) => (forall x. cxt x => x -> result) -> result` and then `f @Show Showable` with `-XTypeApplications`

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for posting my own answer, but this is another alternative I ended up finding:

```
{-# language ExistentialQuantification, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Experiment3 where

import GHC.Exts

data Showable (cxt :: * -> Constraint) = forall x. (cxt ~ Show, cxt x) => Showable x
instance Show (Showable Show) where showsPrec p (Showable x) = showsPrec p x

f :: cxt () => (forall x. cxt x => x -> result cxt) -> result cxt
f mkResult = mkResult ()

resultStr :: String
resultStr = show (f Showable :: Showable Show)
```

Unfortunately it requires an explicit type signature in `show (f Showable)` while my goal was to get type inference (or rather, some kind of constraint inference) through `Showable`. So this answer is not a solution as such, but rather another counter example to what I wanted.

I will accept the answer by Cirdec since it guided me to this conclusion.